# I'm getting values but not as it should be

Tags: arrays, c, function

Problem: Write a program in C to get the largest element, smallest element, sum of all elements and multiplication of all elements of an array using the functions. (Make four different functions for four calculations and call them for one array given by user).

I think I'm getting error because of `i` and `n`.

I'm a beginner and I can't explain every thing line by line. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

// defined Max function int Max(int arr[], int); 
// defined Min function int Min(int arr[], int); 
// defined Sum function int Sum(int arr[], int); 
// defined Mul function int Mul(int arr[], int); 

int main() { 
    int i, n, arr[100];

    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Input %d elements in the array: \n",n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {

            printf("element - %d : ",i);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
    n = Max( arr, n);
    printf("The largest element in the array is : %d", n);
    n = Min( arr, n);
    printf("\nThe smallest element in the array is : %d", n);
    n = Sum( arr, n);
    printf("\nThe sum of all the elements in the array is : %d", n);
    n = Mul( arr, n);
    printf("\nThe multiplication of all the elements in the array is : %d", n);
    return 0;
}

int Max(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (max<arr[i])
                  max=arr[i];
        }
    return max;
}

int Min(int arr[], int n)
{
    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (min>arr[i])
                  min=arr[i];
        }
    return min;
}

int Sum(int arr[], int n)
{
    int sum = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    return sum;
}

int Mul(int arr[], int n)
{
    int mul = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            mul *= arr[i];
        }
    return mul;
}
```

Comment: In the "sum" and "mul" functions (and "max" and "min" too) you are using `arr[0]` twice. sum **is not** `arr[0] + arr[0] + arr[1] + ... + arr[n-1]`.

Comment: Beware that your sum and (especially) product do not overflow. For example 13! (factorial) will overflow an `int` product yet you can have 100 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in one comment, your `for` should start from 1, otherwise you use the element 0 twice, and thus producing always a wrong result. Here is how the `for` related to `Mul` function should appear, just apply the same for other ones:

```
int mul = arr[0];
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{ 
   mul *= arr[i];
}
return mul;
```

In addition to the above, there is another bug in your code, which is the way you use the variable `n`. 
As far as I see, that variable stores the number of elements of the array. It is a valid input for all the sub-routines, but you cannot re-assign it with the result of each of them. In this way, it's like you are invoking the sub-routines always with a different array size, and of course you get unexpected results.
So, one possible solution would be to define and use another local variable which holds the results from each sub-routines.

To help you with your issue, I fixed your code, it works fine now. There you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

// defined Max function int Max(int arr[], int); 
// defined Min function int Min(int arr[], int); 
// defined Sum function int Sum(int arr[], int); 
// defined Mul function int Mul(int arr[], int); 

int main() { 
    int i, n, op_res, arr[100];

    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Input %d elements in the array: \n",n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {

            printf("element - %d : ",i);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
    op_res = Max( arr, n);
    printf("The largest element in the array is : %d", op_res);
    op_res = Min( arr, n);
    printf("\nThe smallest element in the array is : %d", op_res);
    op_res = Sum( arr, n);
    printf("\nThe sum of all the elements in the array is : %d", op_res);
    op_res = Mul( arr, n);
    printf("\nThe multiplication of all the elements in the array is : %d", op_res);
    return 0;
}

int Max(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (max<arr[i])
                  max=arr[i];
        }
    return max;
}

int Min(int arr[], int n)
{
    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (min>arr[i])
                  min=arr[i];
        }
    return min;
}

int Sum(int arr[], int n)
{
    int sum = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    return sum;
}

int Mul(int arr[], int n)
{
    int mul = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            mul *= arr[i];
        }
    return mul;
}
```

Comment: You should accept the answer and upvote :D

Comment: Upvote recorded but won't show publicly bcz my reputation <10

Comment: No worries, that's ok. I am just happy to help, but I am also glad you accepted the answer. :)